# Search Result inconsistency Pytube

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

I am trying to make a youtube video downloader that searches, shows you the results and when you click on one, downloads the video. I am using pytube for youtube connection and tkinter for GUI. But I am facing this problem: When I click on a when I click on a video another search result gets downloaded. For example search results are, A, B, C, D, E when I click on B it downloads D.
Here is the code:

```
import pytube
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as font

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Video Downloader")
root.geometry('1000x1000')

entry = tk.Entry(root, width=400, font=("Tahoma 30"))
entry.pack()

def Download(link):
    youtubeObject = pytube.YouTube(link)
    youtubeObject = youtubeObject.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    try:
        youtubeObject.download()
    except:
        print("An error has occurred")
    print("Download is completed successfully")

def ComputeMinuteLenght(num):
    if num//60 == 0:
        return "<1 minute"
    elif num//60 == 1:
        return "1 minute"
    else:
        str(num//60)+" minutes"

def ButtonFunc():
    s = pytube.Search(entry.get())

    for v in s.results:
        answerButton = tk.Button(root, text=v.title + "-> "+ComputeMinuteLenght(v.length), command=lambda: Download(v.watch_url))
        answerButton['font'] = font.Font(size=15)
        answerButton.pack()

SubmitButton = tk.Button(root, text="Show Results", command=ButtonFunc)
SubmitButton['font'] = font.Font(size=30)
SubmitButton.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

I tried to change v to v+5 or etc. but it doesn't consistently download the search result that is five results away and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to code right now but I think the problem is at `ButtonFunc` lambda "command=lambda: Download(v.watch_url)"

You can update it to:

```
for v in s.results:
  answerButton = tk.Button(root, text=v.title + "-> "+ComputeMinuteLenght(v.length), command=lambda vid=v: Download(vid.watch_url))
  answerButton['font'] = font.Font(size=15)
  answerButton.pack()
```

I am out of town and not able to use my pc therefore I didn't tried this but I think this is the problem, you can check.

Comment: Thank you so much. I never thought about the lambda when i was trying to find the bug.

Comment: @ulsaa your most welcome!